# Java replacing method with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following method

```
private void initializeMoveOnClick(final Group window){
    window.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            //do some stuff
        }
    });
}
```

How do I go about replacing the overrided handle method declaration with a lambda expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have mostly two ways to do it:

```
private void initializeMoveOnClick(final Group window){
    window.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> runSomeMethod());
}
```

and:

```
private void initializeMoveOnClick(final Group window){
    window.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this::eventFilter);
}
private void eventFilter(MouseEvent e) {
    //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `EventHandler` is an interface with a single method, you can replace the anonymous class with lambda expression like this:

```
private void initializeMoveOnClick(final Group window){
    window.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (mouseEvent) -> {});
}
```